# Can't get imagemapster to highlight (Uncaught TypeError)

Tags: jquery, image, highlight, imagemapster

I am having som issues with getting imagemapster to work properly.

Try look at this:
http://wecu.dk/test.html

It is supposed to highlight when mouseover on some areas of the house.

I have imported "jquery-1.7.1.js" and "jquery.imagemapster.js" to my library.

I don't know what's wrong, and I am very new to jQuery.. 
It works when I try here: [http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/3101/]

I tried a lot of solutions and have done some testing too, but no luck at all! :(

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your [custom Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZxqA.jpg) (screenshot) with a [$(document).ready()-function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). It will wait with running your Javascript until the page is ready for it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Put your code within this function
});
```

I tried adding it locally on my machine and the highlighting then worked well.

Have a great day!

Andreas